# Multiple where clauses in one row sql

Tags: sql, count, where-clause

I want to take the below statement and fuse it into one query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count1 WHERE Month='11' AND Flag = 1
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count2 WHERE Month='11' AND Flag = 2
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count1 WHERE Month='12' AND Flag = 1
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count2 WHERE Month='12' AND Flag = 2
```

I want this to display as one query with columns count1 and count2 and rows month 11 and month 12.

Is there a syntax for this?

Comment: *Why* is month a string?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The data is an excel sheet import that has a lot of junk data in it. I'm initially pulling in everything as a string so I can begin to clean the data into a more manageable format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can combine `SUM` and `CASE` to get various counts in one go:

```
SELECT
    Month,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Flag=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as count1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Flag=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as count2
from
    ...
WHERE Month in ('11','12')
GROUP BY
    Month /* Other columns? */
```

Comment: The OP only wants two columns.

Comment: @af, it can't be done in two columns and still be able to tell which month each count is for

Comment: I used a variation of this and got two columns fine with one column for the month. That's what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

**With two columns only**, it can be something like this:

```
select
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename WHERE Month='11' AND Flag = 1) as 'count1'
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename WHERE Month='11' AND Flag = 2) as 'count2'

UNION ALL

select
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename WHERE Month='12' AND Flag = 1), 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename WHERE Month='12' AND Flag = 2)
```

Replace `tablename` with the name of your table.

Comment: perhaps you are missing a , at the end of each line  it should be
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename WHERE Month='11' AND Flag = 1) as 'count1',

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename WHERE Month='11' AND Flag = 2) as 'count2'

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
select
    month, flag, count(*)
from
    table
where
    month in ('11', '12') and
    flag in (1, 2)
group by
    month, flag;
```

Comment: But op wants one column for each count, and only two rows

Comment: Noted, just figured he'd be processing the output with some code afterwards. I mean, who uses untouched raw SQL in their output? Perhaps that was presumptious of me... :)

Comment: @alexhowansky I actually will be using the raw untouched SQL. This is more of a quick report than an application. I just need to pull the data, and if i can do it fast and in format, it prevents me needing to adjust it by hand into the format I'm looking for.